# RESTclient for Safari

Tags: safari-extensions

Is there a POSTMAN for Chrome equivalent (or alternative to) for Safari in Mac OS X Mavericks? I hate switching between browsers just to be able to test my APIs.

Answer (score 4):

I used an App Store utility called Rested. It's not in Safari, but it's good, and tiny, and does not require running another browser.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using [Talend API Tester Free Edition](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/talend-api-tester-free-ed/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) Chrome extension.